# Can I sync contacts between gmail addresses?

Tags: contacts, gmail, dual-sim

I have a dual sim setup, work and private. I thus also have two email (gmail) addresses registered on the device, work and private. I have many contacts on both, but I want all of them on my private google account. So how can I make sure all accounts are added to my private google account, but not the other way around?

Comment: Are you looking to keep the private account synced or would a one-time export/import suffice? The former may require a third-party contact manager.

Comment: @PFitz I would want it synced every time I make a change. When I change a contact in my contact list, regardless of the origin, I would want the changes saved to my personal address.